# Wordpress is_page not working with blog page not home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a static landing page as the home page and the blog feed page is a separate page called news. The id for the news page is 11. I'm displaying the title like so:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name') . ' - ' . the_title();?></title>
```

But of course on the blog page it loads up the first blog post title instead of the page title. So I tried this:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name');?> - 
<?php if(is_page(11)){?>
News
<?php }else{the_title();}?></title>
```

but it doesn't work, as for some reason it thinks that the blog page is also the article page -_-

Comment: You can try to var_dump `$wp_query`. Also, can you post the code for the page?

Comment: The blog front page is a 'page'. You set it in WP admin

Comment: I think some conflict happened here.
Try add "wp_reset_query();" at the beginning of the .php file, before: "bloginfo('name')..."

Comment: @henrywright you obviously haven't understood the problem, the blog page isn't the front page

Comment: @user1672694 my apologies, I re-read your question and now see what you mean. Can you provide your blog page's loop code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code is OK.
Change it like this:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name') . ' - ' . wp_title();?></title>
```

wp_title() retrieve the page title, according to this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title

Comment: Worked. It returned empty for the non-blog landing page but the conditional was able to work for that page. Thank you